# Add an informative custom message in Woocommerce Checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, notice

I have a WP/Woocommerce based website, and I would like to inform my clients that, whenever they buy something in my shop, the 3% of their order is devolved for charity associations.

I would like to display the exact amount calculated on the total, for example:
Total: 150 €

5 € will be devolved etc.

How can I manage it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could display it as a Woocommerce "success" notice in checkout page, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'print_donation_notice', 10 );
function print_donation_notice() {
    wc_print_notice( sprintf(
        __("%s 3%% of this order will be devolved for charity associations, so an amount of %s.", "woocommerce"),
        '<strong>' . __("Information:", "woocommerce") . '</strong>',
        strip_tags( wc_price( WC()->cart->get_subtotal() * 0.03 ) )
    ), 'success' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that could be a good idea, thank you so much! And what if I would like to show it after the subtotal?

Comment: @Dino9 you will need instead [to override the woocommerce templates via your theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)… The template to be overridden is `checkout/review-order.php` and you will have to create an additional row on the html table…